# MVC 1.0 FormCollection wiped out by running SSRS report

Tags: model-view-controller, forms, reporting-services

I have an MVC 1.0 app with a form that works just fine.

The app also launches an SSRS using the URL ReportServer interface (**Not the Webform ReportViewer Control!).  This also works just fine.

But if I export the generated SSRS report (say to .pdf), and then return to the MVC application, no form will work.  By "not work" I mean that on the Post action, the form collection is not returned.

I'm completely lost as to what could be causing this behavior.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  One site was NTML authenticated, and the other was not.  I had assumed with IE8 and tab-session states that the NTML - non-NTML IE optimization interplay no longer applies.  But this experience proves it does, at least on XP and Vista.

So the solution is to either hack the client registery (I've never thought this approach really practical) or in my case, use 2 sub-domains.  In the latter case, it's important to know that the IE authentication optimization uses the full URL.  So suba.mydomain.com and subb.mydomain.com will each be treated as a unique site by the IE authentication optimization, and hence not lead to the sequential site authentication dependancy problem.

This KB is relevant:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251404